# Return the same types as the passed array parameter

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics, return-type

After several hours of research I managed to create a function that returns an array with the same types as the passed parameter:

```
const parseItems = <T extends unknown[]>(items: [...T]): T => { ... }

const items = parseItems(['hello', 101, true]) // [string, number, boolean]
```

But how could I write the above code without using the spread operator? Something like this:

```
const parseItems = <T extends unknown[]>(items: T): ??? => { ... }
```

Comment: You can't. The **inference site** is where it matters, and the inference site in this case is the argument. Whatever you do for the return type won't change how TypeScript infers `T` when you pass it to `parseItems`.

Comment: Also, why do you *want* to avoid the spread operator/variadic tuples? Why try to make life harder?

Comment: Well, if you don't want spread you can go with something like this. I bet there's a way to create a dynamic amount of `Tuples` but is too late now to think. `type Tuples = [] | [unknown] | [unknown, unknown] | [unknown, unknown, unknown] | [unknown, unknown, unknown] | [unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown] | [unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]; const parseItems = <T extends Tuples>(items: T) => items;`

Comment: Note that the return type annotation is also superfluous